# Fake Israel Visa Stamp on my Passport

Tags: passport-stamps, israel, denial-of-entry

I have an problem here... I applied as DH in Israel not knowing that I was Transacting to a fake agent and the problem is they already stamped fake Israel Visa on my passport. I already traveled here in Qatar but the immigration denied my passport and they said that I will not work here, I will be going back to Philippines because of this fake visa stamp. What will I do?

Comment: Ask your government (the issuer). Probably your passport is not more valid. Very probably you need to have a new passport. Ask also Israely embassy, to be sure the visa is false and "reassure" them you are looking for a real visa (so not to being black listed)

Comment: I assume ‘DH’ means ‘domestic help’? You could report the agent to the Filipino immigration authorities but unfortunately there may be little you can do to remove the entry denial from your travel history. Changing your passport would mean the fake visa itself would no longer be visible but your previous passport will remain associated with your travel record and you’ll have to provide details in any future visa application that asks about previous passports or immigration problems.

Comment: @Traveller: new passport is not to hide the visa. The old passport is probably no more valid ("only authorized authorities may write in the passport"). If it was tampered on one place, it is easier to assume it is entirely tampered.

Comment: How you where "denied"? With a stamp, or just they ask if you would voluntary renounce to enter? Sometime you get the offer to "go away" (and not entering) without prejudices.

Comment: @Giacomo Catenazzi I think you may be being slightly naive. Everyone who uses a fake agency to get a visa and subsequently gets found out, says that they didn’t know the agency was fake.

Comment: @Traveller: we answer many question naively, possibly hinting some possible problems. We should always assume good faith (it was a good policy of Wikipedia), and we cannot in any case help people who tell us a lie. So I try to think most of people were naive youth travellers.But I think you are overgeneralizing. How many people used fake ESTA sites? Or visa facilitators (which help you not going to embassy in person, especially if you live away from capitals [or to provide you also invitation letters so you can travel alone). So I think the question could be genuine (I do not know Philippines)

Answer (score 3):

Tell your government that your passport was damaged/spoiled and request a new one.

This does not resolve your problem that Qatar considers you a liar. They *will* send you back and for the rest of your life you will have to answer "yes" if an application asks "have you ever been denied a visa or deported?"

This will make it much harder to get future visa, but if you lie about the denial and get caught they will definitively reject your application and add a ban in yet another country.

I'm sorry if that sounds unsympathetic and does not answer "what shall I do" but there is little you can do now. Look for work in the Philippines.

Comment: Are you deported if you are refused entry?

Comment: @gnasher729, Qatar seems to be throwing the OP out if I read the post correctly. For example the UK asks "Have  you  ever  been  deported,  removed  or  otherwise  required  to  leave  any  country [...]?"